# Gravity Forms Datepicker in Lightbox

Tags: jquery, datepicker, lightbox2

Hey I'm having an issue with the datepicker in gravity forms (datepicker.js), it seems to be working ok on page but in the [lightbox](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) it's not loading

If you click on the request functions package the lightbox will pop up -
http://www.pacificdunes.com.au/port-stephens-events/#grey

I've found a few people have had similar problems in other overlay scripts and with just the datepicker but nothing with gravity forms and lightbox and I haven't worked out from those how to get it working either.